# How to set Padding so that after cleaning Errors forms get their normal style

Tags: css, angular, forms

In my page There are many forms. After submitting forms An error and warning panel is coming at top bar of page  for which i am changing my two forms(Right one and left one) pading-style using below code which is showing warnins fine :

```
const accountType = document.querySelector('.amtx-account-type') as HTMLElement;
    accountType.style.padding = '0px';
    const repType = document.querySelector('.amtx-rep-code') as HTMLElement;
    repType.style.padding = '0px';
```

But after clearing forms my warnings panel is getting removed as well as my forms have now padding as 0px which is making them hidden inside top panel.

i want help how can i solve this problem so that after clearing warnings panel my forms take padding as their initial style i.e. 68px so that they do not take padding as 0px.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would be NOT injecting CSS properties like this. Use either Angular animations (https://angular.io/guide/animations) or toggle CSS classes (`[class.warning]="isWarningOrErrorVisible"`)